# Axis fake certificate

Tags: java, certificate, axis

I am using axis on `java` to consume a `webservice`. The web service is in https, and I want to avoid the the check for certificate. I found in this forum a solution that tell to put this on my code :

```
AxisProperties.setProperty("axis.socketSecureFactory","org.apache.axis.components.net.SunFakeTrustSocketFactory");
```

I tried it but with no success. I have enabled : `System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");` and I see this in the begining of the log:

```
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1 ......
```

And in the end it gives an error :

```
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't know if it's the same thing, but have u tried `System.setProperty()` instead of `AxisProperties.setProperty()`?

Comment: Yes, i have tried it also, the same thing

Comment: Are you aware that your use of SSL has been highlighted in a [research paper](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~shmat/shmat_ccs12.pdf) (Section 10)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For disable-ing the the protocol is necessary to build a class that implements :SecureSocketFactory and in the method `create` to do this : 
     ((SSLSocket)sslSocket).setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"SSLv3", "TLSv1"});
A good start for this maybe, you can use the implemetation done from : JSSESocketFactory.
The solution for this was based in this question : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128026/how-to-disable-sslv2-socket-protocol-in-axis/9128420#comment11472705_9128420)