# How to disable SSLv2 socket protocol in axis

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, axis

I have a problem with consuming a web service using axis.This happen because axis sent a SSLv2 ClientHello and the server that offer the webservice does not support the SSLv2 protocol. To fix this i have to disable this protocol. The code for disable it in Java is :

```
SocketFactory socketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) socketFactory.createSocket(hostname, port);
socket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"SSLv3", "TLSv1"});
```

I refer to these [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682957/why-does-javas-sslsocket-send-a-version-2-client-hello). Now, the problem is how can I disable this protocol when I am using axis for consuming the webservice?

Comment: That depends on what container you are running in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Axis 2, you should be able to configure an Apache HttpClient 3.x [`SecureProtocolSocketFactory`](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/protocol/SecureProtocolSocketFactory.html) (see the [Axis 2 documentation on the subject](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/http-transport.html#httpsupport)). You should be able to set the enabled protocols in `createSocket` before returning the socket. (You might also be interested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3713147/372643).)

For Axis 1, you should be able to set the `axis.socketSecureFactory` property to your own class name implementing an [Axis `SecureSocketFactory`](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/apiDocs/org/apache/axis/components/net/SecureSocketFactory.html) and configure the socket in the same way there.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.I am using axis 1. I am trying to do the implementation of SecureSocketFactory, but it is not clear for me where i have to put the code that tell to the socket to use the protocols : "SSLv3", "TLSv1" ? I am trying something like this :

Comment: In the `create` method, with returns the socket, before returning your instance of `SSLSocket`, call `setEnabledProtocols` on it.

Answer (score 0):

For Axis 1:

1. Create your custom MySocketFactory which extends SecureScoketFatory.

   ```
   String[] protocols = { "TLSv1" };//provide the list of protocols which you        want to enable
   ((SSLSocket) sslSocket).setEnabledProtocols(protocols);
   ```
2. Then at  your web service client level  provide the System property like below.

   ```
   System.setProperty("axis.socketSecureFactory", "com.custom.MySocketFactory");
   ```